# Difference between QGIS developer version and QGIS stable version for Python programming?

Tags: pyqgis

I am using python and PYQGIS and I have installed QGIS via OSGEOW. I chose the complete advanced install with all packages, libraries and GIS programs.

There is a 2.99 developer's version and the latest stable version (2.18.7).

What additions does the developer's version feature, and what differences does it make for python programming?

Comment: 2.99 is dev version for the coming v3.0 there are some major changes coming... http://blog.qgis.org/2016/02/10/qgis-3-0-plans/ >python  "Qt5/PyQt5/Python3 branch in parallel, actually work on it until it’s ready, make it master and release it as 3.0"

Comment: But such branch does not exist yet, and blog says "Meantime keep working on master (2.x) and keep releasing them every 4 months as usual".

Comment: @Mapperz can i use python 3 and QT5 for pyqgis api ?

Comment: @Mapperz,@user30184 this version is like a demo for new QGIS version ?

Comment: @Mapperz,@user30184 so why i dont have SAGA algorithm on processing ?

Comment: v2.99 will become master v3.0.

Comment: @Mapperz i think that work only with python 3 ?why dont have SAGA algorithms ?

Answer (score 1):

You can browse the latests commits of the master branch https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commits/master. A summary of changes in released versions is in https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/NEWS.

Comment: 2.99 version not have more tools for python programming  ?